# How do I custom name for JavaApplicationStub in install4j?

Tags: install4j

On OS X, the process name of a Java app built with install4j is "JavaApplicationStub". I'd like that to be replaced with something specific for our application.

This would make it easier, for example, to determine which application is ours when running "ps" from Terminal.

How can I do rename JavaApplicationStub?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be adjusted in the install4j IDE, but you can edit the project file in a text editor, look for the "macBundleBinary" attribute and change it to your own name.

Comment: I'm curious if this has changed wince 2015? We are using this too but it gets overwritten every time we update the file with the IDE, which is kind of a pain.

Comment: The "macBundleBinary" attribute should be added to the "launcher" element and if you change it before you open the project with the IDE, the IDE will write it back to disk when you save the project.